# Microsoft outlook.com is not showing embedded images

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, hotmail, outlook.com

i am working on a project in which  am sending email to the user after registration. The problem is emails in all email clients are working perfectly except outlook.com (hotmail.com).
The Logo at the top of email body is not showing, it only shows ALT text instead of image.
Can anybody guide me how i can solve this issue.

Comment: How are you sending the email? what does the generated html look like?

Comment: What is the HTML source? How is that image included?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. 
I used test url for my logo. It consists with ip and links to folder([http://my_ip/account/folder/images/new_logo.png]). Then I changed it to full domain url. It fixed my issue. I think it will help you also.